# How to dynamically set the DataFlowTask : Excel Source in SSIS Package?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

How to dynamically set the DataFlowTask : Excel Source in SSIS Package?

I am loading over 100 excel files which has to be passed through Excel Source.

In the Property of Excel Source / OpenRowset , I have the set condition as 
" Sheet2$A5:K "

I am able to set the Excel Source for one specific file. However, I am not able to set the source in a dynamic approach of loading 100 files in a folder.

Comment: Sounds like you want a Foreach Loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151342/ssis-how-to-loop-through-files-in-folder-and-get-pathfile-names-and-finally-e

Comment: @AaronDietz, thank you.. i need a Foreach Loop.